# Java: Area is slowing runtime

Tags: java, area

I have made a Flappy Bird game. but the sprite is a rectangle, and the image is a bird, like so:

[Bird Sprite Rect Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OrFZ.png)

What happened was that the top left corner, which was far away from the bird when touched any block, then it counts as a collision.

To resolve this, I made an area, which contained the image like so:

[Bird Area Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxh2I.png)

I made the area like this:

where bi is my Buffered Image containing the bird,
and area is the Area which I made that covers the bird's body.

```
      Area area = new Area();
      BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width,height,TYPE_RGB);
      bi.getGraphics().drawImage(image,0,null);
      for(int xx=0;xx<bi.getWidth();xx++)
        for(int yy=0;yy<bi.getHeight();yy++) {

            if(bi.getRGB(xx,yy)!=-16777216) {
                area.add(new Area(new Rectangle(xx+x, yy+y, 1, 1)));
            }
        }
```

*Note: -16777216 is the code for no color
x: is the x position of the entire sprite
y: is the y position of the entire sprite

The actual problem is, that in each iteration of my game loop, I have to remake the area, which is leading to a decrease in the speed of my game and making it very slow and laggy. is there a way in which I can use area and maintain the speed? will converting it to a polygon help in any way?

Comment: Look into the [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Shape.html) interface. I would give you implementation details, but it's late here, and you know how to use Google.

Comment: That sounds like your `area` object is continuously growing. At the start of each iteration do you clear out all old `Area` objects?

Comment: Can you post your `Area` code and how you remake (call) the area?

Comment: Ok, I updated my code, now it contains the creation of the Area

Comment: @MarsAtomic Can you please elaborate on how shape would help me in this scenario?

Comment: *`in each iteration of my game loop, I have to remake the area`*. Why? Couldn't you just create the area once and move and rotate it like the picture (see `Area.transform(...)`). Anyways, a less detailed collision box would also do the trick and be way faster. A 20 point polygon should be more than enough.

Comment: @Socowi Thank you. Can you please elaborate that in an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure where you need more details. Constructing the `Area` once and transforming it like the actual picture should be clear I think. With the less detailed collision box I meant creating an `new Area(new Polygon(...))` by providing only a few manually specified points (20 or so) rather than constructing an Area from the individual pixels. The player won't even notice that the collision isn't pixel perfect. You can manually select this coarse polygon in any html image map creator, for instance this one: https://www.image-map.net/ (select polygon and draw around the bird).